# how to configure job.properties for oozie workflow

Tags: hive, oozie

Firt of all i am new to this oozie, i don't know how to do in practical. i am triying to run the default examples file with hive actions in oozie...

This is my Job.properties file

`nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020`
`jobTracker=localhost:8021`
`queueName=default`
`examplesRoot=exampless`

`oozie.libpath=/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/examples-lib`

`oozie.wf.application.path=/practical/examples/apps/hive`

note: /practical/examples/apps/hive its a path of hdfs containing workflow.xml file

I am getting this **error**:

> Error: E0504 : E0504: Workflow app directory
>   [/practical/examples/apps/hive] does not exist (but im having
>   workflow.xml file in that path)

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you should set 
oozie.wf.application.path to 
hdfs://hostname:8020/practical/examples/apps/hive
instead of /practical/examples/apps/hive as it is not an hdfs location and 
it will start searching in local file system not hdfs.

Example:
nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
oozie.wf.application.path =  
${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/practical/examples/apps/hive
```